# Smooth scrolling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, anchor-scroll

I know there are questions about smooth scrolling on SF already but I am unable to find what I want. Already used improved smooth scroll script but it's the one on this website http://michaelacevedo.com I want to achieve. When you click on a link then it starts off real slow and then speedy animation takes you to the desired section. It's really different than other smooth scrolls. Can anyone help implement this effect and explain what's the code doing. 
Thanks

Comment: watch out that smooth scrolling using jQuery on a browser / OS that supports smooth scrolling natively will result in bad experience for the user

Comment: Thanks. And how you can overcome this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var top = $('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    },500, 'easeOutExpo');

    return false;
});
```

Then select the easing you want https://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html