# Smooth scrolling implementation with jquery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

All,

I'm trying to implement smooth same page scrolling but so far none of the solutions have worked. The latest code I have (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722835/smooth-scrolling-with-jquery)) doesn't do anything.

Here the function:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5ueb9p3/

Am I missing something completely obvious? In my code I am linking to jquery 3.2, popper and bootstrap (4 beta 2)

Comment: I don't know what you're actually working with since you didn't include it, but the fiddle you link to is broken -- it doesn't include jQuery at all, and you don't have any text in your `<a>` tag, so I'm not sure how you were clicking anything. However, after fixing those errors, the code works fine.

Comment: By the way, StackOverflow has a built-in code snippet editor, so you should use that in the future instead of linking to an external site like jsfiddle, codepen, etc.

Comment: Hey, I actually received the opposite feedback last time (include a fiddle). Idk why it didn't save correctly though.

Comment: It's possible that whoever gave the feedback wasn't aware of the snippet editor (unless they specifically said to use a fiddle instead of that, in which case, no idea...), but the built-in snippet display works well and allows the code to be immediately viewable. The problem with external sites is that one day they may go down and future viewers won't be able to see whatever code was being talked about. Also, network restrictions sometimes keep people from being able to view certain sites, but that won't be a problem if all the code is here.

Comment: Ok fair enough.

Comment: I'm still struggling though, it doesn't work for me even after fixing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up solving it with another code snippet reproduced below. Original source is also included. I added a small modification in the smoothScroll function to account for the navbar offset (in my case 140) and commented out the line that sets the location to the anchor since that would nullify the above.

```
/* Smooth scrolling
   Changes links that link to other parts of this page to scroll
   smoothly to those links rather than jump to them directly, which
   can be a little disorienting.

   sil, http://www.kryogenix.org/

   v1.0 2003-11-11
   v1.1 2005-06-16 wrap it up in an object
*/

var ss = {
  fixAllLinks: function() {
    // Get a list of all links in the page
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // Walk through the list

    for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
      var lnk = allLinks[i];
      if ((lnk.href && lnk.href.indexOf('#') != -1) &&
          (!(lnk.classList.contains('noTouchy'))) &&
          ( (lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ||
        ('/'+lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ) && 
          (lnk.search == location.search)) {
        // If the link is internal to the page (begins in #)
        // then attach the smoothScroll function as an onclick
        // event handler
        ss.addEvent(lnk,'click',ss.smoothScroll); //all anchor points now have the smoothscroll function
      }
    }
  },

  smoothScroll: function(e) {
    // This is an event handler; get the clicked on element,
    // in a cross-browser fashion
    if (window.event) {
      target = window.event.srcElement;
    } else if (e) {
      target = e.target;
    } else return;

    // Make sure that the target is an element, not a text node
    // within an element
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
      target = target.parentNode;
    }

    // Paranoia; check this is an A tag
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a') return;

    // Find the <a name> tag corresponding to this href
    // First strip off the hash (first character)
    anchor = target.hash.substr(1);
    // Now loop all A tags until we find one with that name
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var destinationLink = null;
    for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
      var lnk = allLinks[i];
      if (lnk.name && (lnk.name == anchor)) {
        destinationLink = lnk;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!destinationLink) destinationLink = document.getElementById(anchor);

    // If we didn't find a destination, give up and let the browser do
    // its thing
    if (!destinationLink) return true;

    // Find the destination's position
    var destx = destinationLink.offsetLeft; 
    var desty = destinationLink.offsetTop - 140;
    var thisNode = destinationLink;
    while (thisNode.offsetParent && 
          (thisNode.offsetParent != document.body)) {
      thisNode = thisNode.offsetParent;
      destx += thisNode.offsetLeft;
      desty += thisNode.offsetTop;
    }

    // Stop any current scrolling
    clearInterval(ss.INTERVAL);

    cypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();

    ss_stepsize = parseInt((desty-cypos)/ss.STEPS);
    ss.INTERVAL =
setInterval('ss.scrollWindow('+ss_stepsize+','+desty+',"'+anchor+'")',10);

    // And stop the actual click happening
    if (window.event) {
      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
    if (e && e.preventDefault && e.stopPropagation) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  },

  scrollWindow: function(scramount,dest,anchor) {
    wascypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();
    isAbove = (wascypos < dest);
    window.scrollTo(0,wascypos + scramount); //timing
    iscypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();
    isAboveNow = (iscypos < dest);
    if ((isAbove != isAboveNow) || (wascypos == iscypos)) {
      // if we've just scrolled past the destination, or
      // we haven't moved from the last scroll (i.e., we're at the
      // bottom of the page) then scroll exactly to the link

        window.scrollTo(0,dest);
      // cancel the repeating timer
      clearInterval(ss.INTERVAL);
      // and jump to the link directly so the URL's right
      //location.hash = anchor;
    }
  },

  getCurrentYPos: function() {
    if (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)
      return document.body.scrollTop;
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
      return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset)
      return window.pageYOffset;
    return 0;
  },

  addEvent: function(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    // addEvent and removeEvent
    // cross-browser event handling for IE5+,  NS6 and Mozilla
    // By Scott Andrew
    if (elm.addEventListener){
      elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
      return true;
    } else if (elm.attachEvent){
      var r = elm.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn);
      return r;
    } else {
      alert("Handler could not be removed");
    }
  } 
}

ss.STEPS = 25;

ss.addEvent(window,"load",ss.fixAllLinks);
```